# Logging end of a run in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql, logging

I have a database, let's say in MySQL, that logs runs of client programs that connect to the database.  When doing a run, the client program will connect to the database, insert a "Run" record with the start timestamp into the "Runs" table, enter its data into other tables for that run, and then update the same record in the "Runs" table with the end timestamp of the run.  The end timestamp is NULL until the end of the run.

The problem is that the client program can be interrupted -- someone can hit Ctrl^C, the system can crash, etc.  This would leave the end timestamp as NULL; i.e. I couldn't tell the difference between a run that's still ongoing and one that terminated ungracefully at some point.

I wouldn't want to wrap the entire run in a transaction because the runs can take a long time and upload a lot of data, and all of the data from a partial run would be desired.  (There will be lots of smaller transactions during the run, however.)  I also need to be able to view the data in real-time in another SQL connection as it's being uploaded by a client, so a mega-transaction for the entire run would not be good for that purpose.

During a run, the client will have a continuous session with the SQL server, so it would be nice if there could be a "trigger" or similar functionality on the connection closing that would update the Run record with the ending timestamp.  It would also be nice if such a "trigger" could add a status like "completed successfully" vs. "terminated ungracefully" to boot.

Is there a solution for this in MySQL?  How about PostgreSQL or any other popular relational database system?

Comment: Why not have the process that does the initial insert return a TrackingID for the current run? Then your application will know which one it needs to mark as complete at the end. If it never gets to the end then you won't have an end time. Even if you could this kind of trigger thing how would you know which connection belonged to which row?

Comment: I think the "RunId" (primary key of the "Runs" table) is the kind of tracking ID you mean, right?  Are you saying there should be a separate client "clean-up" process that should be used after any run crashes, that should track what the last run was and update the DB to put the end timestamp?  I was hoping something automatic could happen on the DB server end.  Sorry if I misunderstand your response...

Comment: I am thinking you would get the RunID in the application after it initially inserts. Then when the application finishes whatever it runs it would simply update that row. Easy enough for runs that complete. Those with NULL for an endtime either are still running or crashed. You could add some error handling to each step but that could get cumbersome quickly. Again, if you did this on connection close consider how bad that would be. If you open a connection for maintenance it will fire your logic. Probably not what you want to happen.